Automatically serialize nested null objects
I have a set of classes structured as follows:
public class A implements Serializable {
    String prop1;
    String prop2;
    B prop3;
}

public class B implements Serializable {
    String nestedProp4;
    String nestedProp5;
    C nestedProp6;
}

public class C implements Serializable {
    String nestedProp7;
}

I need to serialize an instance of class A. Here is the code I'm using:
A obj = new A();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(obj);

The actual result of the serialization is:
{
    "prop1": null,
    "prop2": null,
    "prop3": null
}

However, I need the result to include the nested structure with null values for the properties, like this:
{
    "prop1": null,
    "prop2": null,
    "prop3": {
        "nestedProp4": null,
        "nestedProp5": null,
        "nestedProp6": {
            "nestedProp7": null
        }
    }
}

Is there an automatic way or configuration annotation to achieve this serialization without using reflection or setting default values?
Additionally, I have many properties in these classes, so I prefer not to add annotations to each property. Annotations at the top of the classes are allowed.

In the result you want to achieve, prop3 is clearly not null even if you think so. What's the real use case?

In the code you posted, obj.prop3 is null. You didn't populate it with an object of type B containing nulls; likewise for the C type object inside the B object.  It's doing exactly what you told it to do, and if you want the entire structure serialized you need to initialize it.

This cannot be covered by Jackson annotations, it is a matter of java null management.
Consider the following cases:
public class B2 extends B {
  String additionalNestedProp;
}

public static void main() {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  A obj1 = new A();
  System.out.println(mapper.valueToTree(obj1));

  A obj2 = new A();
  obj2.setProp3(new B());
  System.out.println(mapper.valueToTree(obj2));

  A obj3 = new A();
  obj3.setProp3(new B2());
  System.out.println(mapper.valueToTree(obj3));
}

The output will be this:
{
    "prop1": null,
    "prop2": null,
    "prop3": null
}
{
    "prop1": null,
    "prop2": null,
    "prop3": {
        "nestedProp4": null,
        "nestedProp5": null,
        "nestedProp6": null
    }
}
{
    "prop1": null,
    "prop2": null,
    "prop3": {
        "nestedProp4": null,
        "nestedProp5": null,
        "nestedProp6": null,
        "additionalNestedProp": null
    }
}

If you wanted the mapper to nest null objects, it wouldn't be able to tell whether it should serialize to case 2 or 3, as it uses the actual type of the object it's deserializing to determine the properties, instead of the declared type. If that object is null, it can't determine the type at all, and can't construct the serialized object (Or even if an object should be created in the first place, what if B2 has an annotation that makes it serialize to a string instead of a JSON object?)
In essence, in case 2, A is not completely null. prop3 in obj2 is set to a non-null object of type B, which can then have null fields. If you want to continue the nesting, you'll have to use default empty objects in some form, as Jackson can't determine which properties to include only based on the declared type of a field.
Related, you can use @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT) to not serialize property objects that have default properties (i.e., the same properties they would have if created with a zero-argument constructor)

Good case coverage and in-depth answer.
